# Sounds that snow make

Tags: meaning

What is a word that describes the sound snow makes when hitting another frozen or hard surface. Thinking more specifically like snow hitting the frozen branches and leaves on a tree.

Comment: If you're talking about snow falling from the sky, the common poetic way to describe the sound is *whispering*. (Although, in my experience, it's actually a soft *hissing* sound.)

Comment: Given either that the Inuit are said to have dozens of words for *snow* itself or that clearly, snow falling on anything but a hot surface makes no sound, what's left to worry about, please?